# Python get TID that matches os /proc/[pid]/

Tags: python, python-3.x, multithreading, python-multithreading

I am trying to get the thread IDs (`tid`) that I can use to access `/proc/[tid]/sched`. I can look it up in the PID column of `htop` but when I try to access it from inside python I keep getting `-1`.

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3
import ctypes
import threading 

def get_tid():
    libc = ctypes.cdll.LoadLibrary('libc.so.6')
    print(libc.syscall(224))

threading.Thread(target=get_tid).run()
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's syscall 186 for me on Ubuntu 18.04

```
import ctypes

def get_tid():
    """System call gettid on Linux, returning thread-id."""
    return ctypes.CDLL('libc.so.6').syscall(186)
```

---

Python 3.8 introduced [threading.get_native_id()](https://docs.python.org/3/library/threading.html#threading.get_native_id)

> Return the native integral Thread ID of the current thread assigned by the kernel. This is a non-negative integer. Its value may be used to uniquely identify this particular thread system-wide (until the thread terminates, after which the value may be recycled by the OS).
>
> Availability: Windows, FreeBSD, Linux, macOS, OpenBSD, NetBSD, AIX.

Comment: You are right, how did you determine it was `186`? I got `224` by finding `unistd.h` online.

Comment: @chew socks I'm using it myself so I had it already in my lib. I picked it up once [here](https://filippo.io/linux-syscall-table/)